# iOS credit card processing

Tags: ios5, credit-card, payment-processing

I am looking to develop an app that accepts credit card information for non-digital products. In other words, In-App purchase does not apply in this case. What I'm looking to do is VERY much like the [Chipotle app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chipotle-ordering/id327228455?mt=8) with which you can purchase food.

What is the best way to facilitate this type of transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, In-App purchase does not apply to non-digital products. For your type of transaction, there are a few options on the market, but the cheapest and easiest solution seems to be [ZooZ](http://www.zooz.com).

Your users will be able to check out with credit cards or PayPal. I think you'll find that the seamless user experience will result in high conversion rates.

I should note: I have the privilege of working at ZooZ :)

Comment: You give full disclosure. Nice. But keep in mind that you're simply advertising ZooZ at the moment. Calling it "the cheapest and easiest" might not be completely unbiased. And all your answers so far are essentially the same. The [FAQ on promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) also states that "if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons", which you might want to keep in mind.