# accepting credit card payments ios

Tags: ios5, ios4, ios6, credit-card, stripe-payments

How can I accept credit card payments in my iphone app?

I wanted to do the following

- Allow users to give their credit card information
- When they do, send credit card to my server using https and proces credit card using stripe on my server.

Is that the right way to do this technically? How can I make sure the credit card information will stay secure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Integrating credit card payments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762096/ios-integrating-credit-card-payments). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9690414/62576.

Comment: I want to know if I can just send the information via https and how? what is the secure way of processing payments using an api call to my website... thanks.

Comment: Here are some popular payment processors: [http://www.ogone.com/](http://www.ogone.com/) [http://www.realexpayments.com/](http://www.realexpayments.com/) [http://www.sagepay.com/](http://www.sagepay.com/) [http://www.worldpay.com/](http://www.worldpay.com/) [http://paypal.com/](http://paypal.com/) [http://www.zooz.com/](http://www.zooz.com/) [https://stripe.com/](https://stripe.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Stripe's iOS bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios) to easily accept your customers' payment information.

This library uses our create token API call to securely send any sensitive data to our servers. We'll then turn that into a token and pass it back to your application – you can submit this to your server to [create an actual charge](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) as normal.